# HTML5 video player Query

Tags: iphone, ios, html, video-streaming

I'm a newbie in HTML5 programming & not sure what i face currently is a bug or expected feature!

While playing a video (For Eg, in youtube.com or sublimevideo.net link) in a web browser the control bar appears & also it plays in the same page. But While playing the same in an iphone, it plays in iphone's default player but not in the same page. Is this the normal behaviour of iPhone? If yes, can anyone please send me a link which provides more insight on this?

Thanks in advance for clarifying & letting me know!!

Answer (score 1):

On the iPhone (and on iPod touch), when a video plays, it plays in full screen, no matter what. Therefore, it's safe to say that this is normal behaviour.

If you read the first paragraph of [this webpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html), it should pretty much echo out what I just stated.

Hope it helps! :)